# How can I stop a specific user control from caching when page caching is enabled?

Tags: asp.net, caching, user-controls

I have a master page with a user control on it.

I have a page that using the above master page and I am caching this page.  But I don't want to cache the user control.

What code do i need to apply for the user control in order to load every time?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227429(v=vs.100).aspx